# Adding event to Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

We are developing application using API Google. During this process we faced with some difficulties.

We used php-sdk that is on this page "code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/" We used Google Calendar service. We followed documentation located here: "developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/" sections Calendars and Events.

Source data: -Access is allowed to Google Calendar service located here "code.google.com/apis/console/" -Required user authorization is requested (based on documentation here: "developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)"

Task: Adding event to calendar.
Action: We send Post-Request to https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}/events?calendarId={calendarId}&alt=json&key={API Key}

Request Body :

```
{

"\u0000*\u0000__creatorType":"EventCreator",

"\u0000*\u0000__creatorDataType":"",

"\u0000*\u0000__organizerType":"EventOrganizer",

"\u0000*\u0000__organizerDataType":"",

"\u0000*\u0000__attendeesType":"EventAttendee",

"\u0000*\u0000__attendeesDataType":"array",

"\u0000*\u0000__startType":"EventDateTime",

"\u0000*\u0000__startDataType":"",

"start":{

"date":"",

"timeZone":"Europe\/Moscow",

"dateTime":"2012-0408T12:00:00+04:00"

},

"location":"sdasdwqwqesaddsa",

"\u0000*\u0000__originalStartTimeType":"EventDateTime",

"\u0000*\u0000__originalStartTimeDataType":"",

"\u0000*\u0000__gadgetType":"EventGadget",

"\u0000*\u0000__gadgetDataType":"",

"description":"sadasdzxczxcasdsaweqqwasd",

"\u0000*\u0000__extendedPropertiesType":"EventExtendedProperties",

"\u0000*\u0000__extendedPropertiesDataType":"",

"\u0000*\u0000__endType":"EventDateTime",

"\u0000*\u0000__endDataType":"",

"end":{

"date":"",

"timeZone":"Europe\/Moscow",

"dateTime":"2012-04-08T19:00:00+04:00"

},

"\u0000*\u0000__remindersType":"EventReminders",

"\u0000*\u0000__remindersDataType":"",

"summary":"wqeqwesadasewqe"

}
```

Note: To form object of event we used code (same as in example here developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert section Examples)

```
Result: API returns an error with code 400 (Bad Request)
```

**Answer from API ( with headers)**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 Date: Fri, 06 Apr 2012 05:53:55 GMT Expires: Fri, 06 Apr 2012 05:53:55 GMT Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Server: GSE Transfer-Encoding: chunked 

{ "error": {

 "errors": [

 { "domain": "global",

 "reason": "badRequest",

 "message": "Bad Request" } 

],

 "code": 400, 

"message": "Bad Request"

 } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Play around w/ this tool. I'm having the same issue. It works in the explorer, but not on my rails server.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#try-it

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you mention (on http://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference) documents the REST interface to the Google Calendar API. The PHP client library, however, works differently and is unfortunately barely documented.

I used the sample included with the Google PHP API client (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/calendar/simple.php). You'll need to generate an oAuth client ID, secret etc. in Google's API console (how this works is documented in the documentation of the API client).

All other documentation about the calendar PHP API is (AFAIK) only to be found in the comments of the `Google_CalendarService` class: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php

You can add a new event to Google Calendar using the following code:

```php
$event = new Google_Event();

// Event title and location
$event->setSummary('Event title');
$event->setLocation('Some location');

// Start and end time of the event
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2013-08-08T14:00:00+02:00');
$event->setStart($start);

$stop = new Google_EventDateTime();
$stop->setDateTime('2013-08-08T16:00:00+02:00');
$event->setEnd($stop);

// Insert event in calendar.
// 'primary' may be replaced with a full @group.calendar.google.com calendar ID.
$createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('primary', $event);
```